# File upload - maximum upload size of 0 B

Tags: upload

I just upgraded Craft to the latest version, and this error now shows up.

```
The file “myfile.jpg” could not be uploaded, because it exceeds the maximum upload size of 0 B
```

Any fix ? Everything worked fine before the update.
Thanks !

Comment: Is this just 1 file or does it happen with all files?

Comment: all the files, whatever their size is

Comment: Enable devMode and try checking your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for any related upload errors.

Comment: So I looked inside the craft.log file, removed everything inside and tried to upload a picture. From the moment when I click "upload file" to the selection of the file and then the javascript alert of 0 B, nothing is written inside the log file.

Comment: Hrm... anything in your web server's error logs?

Comment: Also, are you using GD or Imagick and what is the version?

Comment: GD with php 5.5.12. But everything worked fine until I upgraded craft cms. I think the problem comes from a javascript error as no ajax call is made.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, changing `post_max_size` in `php.ini` to something other than 0 (I used 8M) did it for me.

I'm not sure why this works: `php.ini` says a value of 0 should disable the limit altogether, and this was never an issue on my other Craft installs. Perhaps a bug?